# Clob Data filed replacement issue in Oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle

my Input string

```
Employee[10|||Aryan|||CA|||USA|||URBAN|||IT 
ENGINEER+++20|||Arjun|||FA|||USA|||RULER|||DEVELOPER]
```

My output should be

```
[
 {Employee Name : Aryan,Employee ID:10,Emploee Role:IT ENGINEER}
   ,
 {Employee Name : Arjun,Employee ID:20,Emploee Role:DEVELOPER}
]
```

I tried multiple scenarios which are not working as expected

Comment: Which version of Oracle? Also, do you just what to format the output of a query or do you want to update the contents of the column? The more information you provide regarding your actual requirements teh more likely you are to get helpful responses in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 0):

The below is written assuming you are running a oracle version pre 12c which adds support for JSON.

This is not something you are going to be able to do with a simple replace.

It will need to be a function / procedure.  To give you some idea see below anonymous block this will just output the string, you will need to adapt it to update your field if that is what you need.

I added a third row to your input string as first, last, and lines in the middle all need to be handled differently so needed three records to fully test.

Note CHR(13) = Carriage return, CHR(10) = Line Feed, CHR(9) = tab.  These are just try and match your formatting and can be excluded if the exact formatting is not necessary.

```
declare

v_input clob default 'Employee[10|||Aryan|||CA|||USA|||URBAN|||IT ENGINEER+++20|||Arjun|||FA|||USA|||RULER|||DEVELOPER+++30|||BOB|||FA|||USA|||RULER|||DEVELOPER]';
v_line  varchar2(32000) default null;
v_output clob default null;
v_exit boolean default false;

begin

loop -- loop until we have no more employees to process
  if instr(v_input, '+++') > 0 then -- not the last line
    if v_output is null then -- first line
      v_line  := substr(v_input, instr(v_input, 'Employee[') + 9, instr(v_input, '+++') -10); -- get a single employee row (first line)
    else
      v_line  := substr(v_input, 1, instr(v_input, '+++') -1); -- get a single employee row (not fist line)
    end if;
    v_input := substr(v_input, instr(v_input, '+++') + 3); -- trim off the stuff we have already processed.
  else
    v_line := substr(v_input, 1, length(v_line) - 2); -- get a single employee row (last line)
    v_exit := true;
  end if;
  if v_output is null then -- first line
    v_output := '['||chr(13)||chr(10)||chr(9)||'{'; -- start string
  else 
    v_output := v_output || chr(9) || '{'; -- add the opening brace
  end if;
  v_output := v_output ||'Employee Name : ' || substr(v_line, instr(v_line, '|||', 1, 1) + 3, instr(v_line, '|||', 1, 2)-6) || ','; -- add name
  v_output := v_output ||'Employee ID:' || substr(v_line, 1, 2) || ','; -- add ID
  v_output := v_output ||'Employee Role:' || substr(v_line, instr(v_line, '|||', 1, 5) + 3) || '}'; -- add role
  if v_exit then -- we are on last line so close it all out and exit loop
    v_output := v_output || chr(13) || chr(10) || ']';
    exit;
  else 
    v_output := v_output || CHR(13) || CHR(10) || CHR(9) || CHR(9) || ',' || chr(13) || chr(10); -- not last line so format ready to start new line
  end if;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(v_output);
end;
/
```

The output from this is

```
[
    {Employee Name : Aryan,Employee ID:10,Employee Role:IT ENGINEER}
        ,
    {Employee Name : Arjun,Employee ID:20,Employee Role:DEVELOPER}
        ,
    {Employee Name : BOB,Employee ID:30,Employee Role:DEVELOPER}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will work for any number of entries.

```
SELECT
    '['
    || CHR(10)
    || RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, INDVDL_ENTITY, CHR(10)
                                                 || ','
                                                 || CHR(10)).EXTRACT('//text()')
        ORDER BY
            L
    ).GETCLOBVAL(), CHR(10)
                    || ','
                    || CHR(10))
    || CHR(10)
    || ']'
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            '{Employee Name : '
            || REGEXP_SUBSTR(INDVDL_ENTITY, '[^(/|/|/|)]+', 1, 2)
            || ',Employee ID:'
            || REGEXP_SUBSTR(INDVDL_ENTITY, '[^(/|/|/|)]+', 1, 1)
            || ',Emploee Role:'
            || REGEXP_SUBSTR(INDVDL_ENTITY, '[^(/|/|/|)]+', 1, 6)
            || '}' AS INDVDL_ENTITY,
            L   AS L
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    REGEXP_SUBSTR(VAL, '[^\+\+\+]+', 1, LEVEL) AS INDVDL_ENTITY,
                    LEVEL   AS L
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR('Employee[10|||Aryan|||CA|||USA|||URBAN|||IT ENGINEER+++20|||Arjun|||FA|||USA|||RULER|||DEVELOPER]'
                            , '[^\[]+', 1, 2)) AS VAL
                        FROM
                            DUAL
                    )
                CONNECT BY
                    ( REGEXP_COUNT(VAL, '\+\+\+') + 1 ) >= LEVEL
            )
    );
```

**The output of the query:**

```
[
{Employee Name : Aryan,Employee ID:10,Emploee Role:IT ENGINEER}
,
{Employee Name : Arjun,Employee ID:20,Emploee Role:DEVELOPER}
]
```

Feel free to add as many entries as you want into your input string. (I have tested it with five entries also, It is working fine)  :) :)

As suggested by Shaun, create your own formatting using CHR function.

Thanks.